# Adaptive size classes weired issue

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

My app is universal. I have different constraints for iphone and ipad. Using adaptive size classes, Particularly i am assigning label leading margin to superview = 390, for ipad only. As you can see in attached image.
[image]

It is working fine, when text to label is static, but my text to label is getting changed dynamically and continuously. Because of this, my lablel's position is getting shifted horizontally.

[image: original position of label]

[image: changing to this position]

[image]

Comment: Post screenshot of label position before and after.

Comment: the 'x' position of label continuously get change between 0 and 390. this happens only some times. otherwise it's works fine.

Comment: Not able to imagine the problem, screenshot could be helpful to get more clarity of the issue.

Comment: @BharatModi: I attached screenshot. As you can see, my label(yellow color) changing it's position from this two position, continuously.

Answer (score 0):

**Add Constraints like**

**1. Image View**

[image]

**2. Lable**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am looking solution in adaptive size classes. What your given is apply for all device. I have leading constraint of label in ipad and trailing constrains of label in iphone device; and width, height is constant in both devices.